# QGIS regular points around each polygon in a layer

Tags: qgis, buffer, vector-grid

I have a number of buffered points (somewhere polygons intersect & are dissolved.
I'd like to create regular spaced points grid around EACH polygon -- not ALL polygons.

When I do Vector -> Research Tools -> Regular Points --- I have to choose a layer as an Input Boundary, but it doesn't seem to loop through each shape to create a GRID just for that shape, and instead creates one large grid around ALL shapes. The end result:

[image]

How can I get a point grid for EACH individual shape vs ALL?

Comment: your desired output is a bit unclear. Do you want to get one grid layer for each buffer (so generate lots of different grid layer) or do you want one layer with several grid adjusted to each buffer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "Data Management > Split Vector Layer" tool to split your buffer layer into individual layers, then run the Regular Points tool on each.

Comment: Darren - how can I automate that - I have hundreds of thousands of points/buffers.

Comment: this seems to answer the question for a limited number of buffers, but needs to be automated. If anyone has a solution, please let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to automate this. Perhaps you could 'loop' it somehow in Python? Maybe someone else can help out with a pythonic solution?

Answer (score 0):

You want only the points that lie within the polygons? If so, clip the points layer with the polygon layer: Vector -> Geoprocessing Tools -> Clip.

If I've  understood the question correctly. N.

Comment: No, sorry this is not what I'm asking.  My objective is to have the grid created around each polygon -- I'm OK with it being square (around 1 circle) or rectangular (around a number of dissolved circles) -- but not one giant rectangle grid.

Comment: So you want multiple grid datasets, one for each input polygon?